# 'GiftedChat' API not rendering and unable to send/receive texts

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-gifted-chat

So I'm basically developing a `react-native` Chat app using `firebase` as the backend and I'm stuck at this point where I am unable to send messages and not render the `GiftedChat` Api even. I'm pasting the Home component here can you please help me out. I'm trying to append the message to the `giftedchat` component and render it whenever i press the send button.

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react' import { Text, View, Button }
     from 'react-native' import { GiftedChat } from
     'react-native-gifted-chat' import firebase from '../database/Firebase'
     import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
     
     
     class Home extends Component {
     
         state = {
             messages: [],
             user: 'true',
             userData: null
         }
     
         componentDidMount() {
             const db = firebase.firestore()
             const chatsRef = db.collection('chats')
             this.readUser()
             const unsubscribe = chatsRef.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
     
                 const messagesFirestore = querySnapshot
                     .docChanges()
                     .filter(({ type }) => type === 'added')
                     .map(({ doc }) => {
                         const message = doc.data()
                         return { ...message, createdAt: message.createdAt.toDate() }
                     })
                     .sort((a, b) => b.createdAt.getTime() - a.createdAt.getTime())
                 this.appendMessages(messagesFirestore)
             })
             return () => unsubscribe()
         }
     
         handleSend(messages) {
             const writes = messages.map((m) => chatsRef.add(m))
             Promise.all(writes)
         }
     
         appendMessages = (messages) => {
     
             this.setState((previousMessages) => GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messages))
         }
         async readUser() {
             const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData')
             if (userData) {
                 setUser(JSON.parse(userData))
             }
         }
         async handlePress() {
             const _id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
             const userData = { _id, name }
             await AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData))
         }
     
         handleLogout = () => {
             this.setState(() => ({
                 user: false
             }))
         }
         render() {
             if (this.state.user === 'true') {
     
                 return (<View>
                     <Button title="logout" style={{ width: 200 }} onPress={() => this.handleLogout()}></Button>
                     <GiftedChat messages={this.state.messages} user={this.state.userData}
                         onSend={() => this.handleSend()} />
                 </View>)
             } else {
                 return (<View>
                     {this.props.navigation.navigate("Login")}
                 </View>)
     
             }
         } }
     
     export default Home
```

Comment: I can see that you `handleSend(messages)` but I don't see this value passed in the component under render function here `onSend={() => this.handleSend()}`. I believe you need to fix this to `onSend={() => this.handleSend(messages)}`. Otherwise, check console for errors

Comment: Does'nt make much difference the GiftedChat component isnt rendering

Comment: edit your post with the `GiftedChat`. if the component is not rerendering then its state or its parent state is not changing. add also some logging that it may help you to figure out if the state is changing or not